# How do we encrypt passwords in karate-config.js file?

Tags: karate

I have been using encrypt and decrypt java methods to encrypt and decrypt the passwords a text file containing password and that has been called in java. and any idea how to encrypt and decrypt the password which were there in karate-config.js file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.